# How to update URL of theme CSS in jenkins via groovy?

Tags: css, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use custom css to change jenkins ui and have added the css file in userContent folder and installed https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin. I can update the URL of theme css by going to configuration page inside jenkins. I am trying to automate this via groovy but not getting the right API. Is it even possible to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `cssUrl` or `jsUrl` properties of the `SimpleThemeDecorator` to either a URL string (or `null` to reset it). Changes will take effect immediately.

```groovy
for (pd in PageDecorator.all()) {
  if (pd instanceof org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator) {
    pd.cssUrl = 'https://...'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher. Bdw what is best way to get the plugin api's. I can see that you have used the package name along with the only available class to call the plugin.

Comment: @user_dev I looked at the [plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/simple-theme-plugin/), but you can also check the [extension point list](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+points).

Comment: After adding the url via `pd.setCssUrl(...)` I also needed to add `pd.load()` for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another approach, that represents the configuration in the newer (simple-theme 0.5.1) UI:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.simpletheme.CssUrlThemeElement;

Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.get()

def themeDecorator = jenkins.getExtensionList(org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator.class).first()

themeDecorator.setElements([
  new CssUrlThemeElement('https://some.dummy/url.css')
])

jenkins.save()
```

In case additional config items are needed, just add object instances in the list for `setElements()`. Each would represent an entry in the [configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQgrD.png). The choice of possible classes is [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/simple-theme-plugin/).

Comment: I needed to replace `jenkins.save()` with `themeDecorator.save()` for Jenkins version 2.183 and plugin version 0.5.1.

The problem was the setting did not survive across restarts.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

YELLOW = '\u001B[33m';
RESET  = '\u001B[0m';

def configSimpleTheme(def descriptor, String cssUrl, String jsUrl) {
    if ( !(cssUrl == null || cssUrl.trim().isEmpty()) ) {
        println("${YELLOW}Setting up css style: ${cssUrl.trim()}${RESET}")
        descriptor.cssUrl = cssUrl.trim()
    }
    if ( !(jsUrl == null ||jsUrl.trim().isEmpty()) ) {
        println("${YELLOW}Setting up js: ${jsUrl.trim()}${RESET}")
        descriptor.jsUrl = jsUrl.trim()
    }
    descriptor.save()
}

def jenkinsThemeCSS = System.getenv('JENKINS_THEME_CSS') ?: null
def jenkinsThemeJS  = System.getenv('JENKINS_THEME_JS')  ?: null

def themeDecorator = Jenkins.getInstance().getDescriptor("org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator")
configSimpleTheme(themeDecorator, jenkinsThemeCSS, jenkinsThemeJS)
```